# How to make RecyclerView item size dynamic based on number of items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have to implement a row that should look like this:

[image]

The requirement is to always show a portion of the next item. There's also a requirement that when there are only two items, the two items should expand to occupy the whole width:

[image].

If there's only 1 item, then it should be align at the start end occupy 50% of the width:

[image]

So it seems like I need to vary the size of the RecyclerView item depending on the number of items. How do I achieve this? I was researching about using ItemDecoration but couldn't find any similar example.

Comment: It looks like it is a custom behaviour. I would go in ```RecyclerView``` and ```LayoutManager``` source code to figure out how it should be customized. Likely is ```LayoutManager``` the right choice to go with. You even can write your own from scratch if you would not find a way to customise existing one. Anyway confirm with the customer this requirements which force you to write a custom component (and maintain it!) which significantly increases the budget.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate item width in your adapter:

```
init {
    val itemWidth = when {
        listSize <= 2 -> screenWidth / 2
        else -> screenWidth / 2.5
    }
}
```

and then apply that width to your item views:

```
val lp = viewHolder.rootView.layoutParams
lp.width = itemWidth.toInt()
viewHolder.rootView.layoutParams = lp
```